# Creating a file from a blob

Tags: javascript, safari, form-data, fileapi

I'm in need of some javascript guru. I have this code:

```
handleImage(new File([blob], blob.name, {type: blob.type})).done(/* something */)
```

and

```
handleImage = function (image) {
        // create some fake form data
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("attachment", image);
        formData.append("auto", true);
        formData.append("_csrf", "xxxxxxxxx");

        // post to the server.
        return $.ajax({
            url: "/some/url",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
```

This works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but when using Safari (10.1.1), the server (java / spring mvc) receive in the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` an empty file for "attachment". So it seems to me that `new File([blob], blob.name, {type: blob.type})` is somehow failing.

Any idea of what's wrong here?

Comment: Probably safari's implementation, but why do you even convert it to a File object ? The only difference you'll get will be that you'll have an `lastModified` property on the object... When you append a Blob to your FormData, the third parameter sets the name of the attachment. So `formData.append("attachment", image, image.name);` and `handleImage(blob)` will do exactly the same request as the one you're doing, except that it will work on Safari a,d every other browser that don't support the File constructor (looking at you IE)

Comment: @Kaiido I have another call to `handleImage` that is made with a File parameter

Comment: But once again, File is an subset of Blob. The only difference is that File will add an `name` and an `lastModified` properties. It seems that you already extended your `blob` with its own `name` prop, so now the only difference is this `lastModified` prop, which you could anyway add yourself too. I don't see **one** API that requires an File over an Blob. The only advantage of a File is that you don't need to set the third param of `FormData.append`. So you can make the exact same operations on a File than the ones you'd do on a Blob. (`file instanceof Blob;` is true)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, using the blob directly did fix the issue. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: yes I will as soon as I can get a sit in the train, or in a few hours

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably a bug in safari's young implementation.

**But why do you even convert it to a File object ?**

A File object is a Blob, the only difference being that it has a `name` and a `lastModified` properties. But since you already seem to extend your `blob`, it leaves only this `lastModified`property that you could add too anyway.

The only API I can think of, where it makes a difference if your object is a Blob or a File **is** `FormData.append` method ; where if you pass a File object, it will be able to set the filename automatically. But this method has a third parameter, allowing you to set this filename.

So if you change your code to include `formData.append("attachment", image, image.name);` and call it with `handleImage(blob)` directly, it will do exactly the same request as the one you're doing, except that it will work on Safari and every other browser that don't support the File constructor (looking at you IE).