# jQuery AJAX post failing only in Safari (request body data not posting)

Tags: ajax, safari, html5-canvas, blob, keystonejs

I've built an upload feature that converts a `<canvas>` object to a blob and uploads it through an ajax post (using jQuery 2.1.4) for a Keystonejs (nodejs) site. This is working in Firefox and Chrome but not Safari and I can't figure out why.

I basically followed the [File Upload API](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/docs/guides/API-File-Image-Uploads.md) used in ConnextCMS by Chris Troutner with the exception that I'm not using a `<form>` to construct the upload, it's all done via javascript with `FormData();` and appending a `File();` containing a `blob` in case that clarifies the issue. I'm also using the [blueimp Javascript-Canvas-to-Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) polyfill to support converting to blob in Safari 6+.

Here's the HTML (canvas is constructed through js):

```
  <div id="canvasDiv"></div>
  <button id="saveCanvas" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button">Save</button>
```

And the js:

```
// add canvas to page
    var canvas,
canvasWidth = 306,
canvasHeight = 306; //leave room for canvas border

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
    canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create form data, add blob and make the ajax call
$('#saveCanvas').on('click', function() {

 if (clickX.length, clickDrag.length, clickY.length > 0) {
      if (canvas.toBlob) { //Ensure the toBlob library is loaded
        canvas.toBlob( handleCanvasBlob );
      } else {
        console.error('Could not access toBlob library!');
        return;
      }
} else {
    $('.canvas-footer').prepend('<p class="alert alert-warning text-center col-lg-12">Say something when you Yellp<sub>®</sub> at me!</p>');

    return;
}

function handleCanvasBlob(blob) {

    var newImg = new FormData();

    var bf = new File([blob], 'fileName', {type: blob.type}); // fileName is just a placeholder here

    newImg.append('image_upload', bf, 'filename.png');
    debugger;

    var opts = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/imageupload/create',
        data: newImg,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        //contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        success: function(data) {

          data.image_upload.name = 'yellp_' + data.image_upload._id;
          data.image_upload.filename = 'yellp_' + data.image_upload._id;
          data.image_upload.url = '/uploads/images/' + data.image_upload.image.filename;
          data.image_upload.imageType = 'image/png';
          data.image_upload.createdTimeStamp = new Date();

          //Update the image with the information above.
          $.get('/api/imageupload/'+data.image_upload._id+'/update', data.image_upload, function(data) {

            console.log('Image information updated.');

          })

          //If the metadata update fails:
          .fail(function(data) {

            console.error('The image metadata was not updated. Here is the error message from the server:');
            console.error('Server status: '+err.status);
            console.error('Server message: '+err.statusText);

            alert('Failed to connect to the server while trying to update image metadata!');
          });

          setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.reload();
          }, 100);

        }
    };

    $.ajax(opts);
}

});
```

Safari (Network POST request body):

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_upload"; filename="filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png

(Nothing here)
```

Firefox (Network POST request body):

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_upload"; filename="filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG

���
IHDR��2��2���yÆ\Å��}IDATxíÝýU~ÇñýîoøP*eaùþ Ä H6«$²
(etc…)
```

Maybe something is failing because I'm making the `FormData();` on the fly?

**Side Note:** In FF and Chrome, window reloads and I see the images displayed in the HTML front-end, whereas in Safari they are broken 404s if uploaded through Safari. Maybe it handles urls/routes differently?

Comment: what version of Safari are you testing with? Looks like Safari 9.1 has partial support for File API http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

Comment: Right now I'm testing 10.1.2, was planning on supporting 9.1 later on.

Comment: What happens if you don't append a File but directly the Blob. You can set the filename in the third param of `formData.append(fieldName, blob, fileName)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a file from a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130079/creating-a-file-from-a-blob)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks! that was the issue, in the tutorial Chris mentioned how picky keystonejs was about the data it would accept so I was wrongly thinking that might be it. In this case we do have a duplicate of your link.